# bug in chrome with media queries

Tags: css, google-chrome, media-queries, css-transitions

I have a wierd problem with media queries in chrome

I added **transition** to some elements in my page and created for example 3 states of media queries

when I resize the browser and change the state of media query my elements change size with animation, it's okey and perfect but when I try to keep the size of the browser exactly in the edge of media queries or very close to it my elements quirks and shake, sometimes slow down my page speed like slow motion when I drop the resize, the main problem is when I refresh in that size the page run with that bug

I checked my media queries area

It is :

@media all and (min-width: 1500px)

@media all and (min-width : 1300px) and (max-with: 1499px)

and ...

also I written some css code for those area that media queries didnt cover so my code seems to be correct, it something about chrome or a trick about transition and media queries

for example when I exit 1500px and enter to 1499 it's okey
but when I try to close the size of the browser to 1500 and consecutive change to 1499 and 1500 my elements confuse, there is no problem when I remove the transtion

I UNDERSTAND the possibility of that behavior is very low but i want to fix it.

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle to demonstrate?

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled the second word `width` in `@media all and (min-width : 1300px) and (max-with: 1499px)`