# Bug with browsers' interpretation of @media queries

Tags: html, css

There was a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18285456/bug-in-chrome-with-media-queries) related to this one a long time ago, but which was never responded to or resolved.

I am developing a web site that has distinct screen layouts, which depend upon the width of the viewport/window.

```
@media (min-width: 1120px) { }

/* behaviour as expected */

@media (min-width: 720px) and (max-width: 1119px) { }

/* inconsistent behaviour in Firefox and Edge, mixing elements of above and below */

@media (max-width: 719px) { }
```

In my browser of preference, Chrome, the layouts transition perfectly from the largest screen width to the smallest. The same is true of Opera. However, both Firefox and Edge demonstrate a strange behaviour whereby a single transitional width (of one pixel) causes the browser not to know how to interpret the content.

For example, as the window transitions to the narrowest media width, the title bar becomes narrower, no longer being required to accommodate the main menu, and the menu is hidden (display: none;) and replaced by a small menu icon at the side, which leads to a drop down on hover. But in Firefox and Edge, the main menu is *not* hidden, but instead crammed beside the logo until the window is collapsed one pixel further, after which the behaviour is as expected. *These CSS changes are all under the same @media declaration!*

Interestingly, the behaviour is not consistent. That is, the transition from the largest to the middle width is flawless, but the transition from the middle to the smallest is problematic.

Assuming that it was an issue with fractional size calculations, I added high precision to my @media query like this:

```
@media (max-width: 719.999px)
```

And again, the behaviour was inconsistent. If I adjusted the lower value up (i.e. 719px to 719.999px) there was no change. However, if I instead adjusted the higher value down (i.e. 720px to 719.001px) the problem was partially solved. Certain elements displayed expected behaviour, but again, other anomalies persisted. Similarly, the higher precision worked on Firefox but not Edge.

It seems probable, given the behaviour that I am seeing, that certain boundaries might cause problems, whilst others would not.

*Is this just a known bug that web site developers have learnt to accept, or might there be an easy solution (other than simply selecting a different set of boundaries)?*

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but does it make sense to use decimal numbers with pixels? Like, is half a pixel a thing?

Comment: @sp00m: No, of course it doesn't in this context, but I was thinking back to the days of yore when computers commonly had floating point errors, and trying to imagine how and why these browsers might be misinterpreting the media rules. And it *did* partially solve the problem with Firefox, but not with Edge. (As a side note, half-pixels are used commonly with raster graphics to delineate not only the edge, but the degree of alpha applied to those pixels at the edge.)

Comment: Please update you question with a specific example of this issue.

Comment: And `raster graphics` !== `website browsers` ;-)

Comment: @Martin: I have provided one specific example of the behaviour, but I should mention that the same thing happens with other elements on the page at that point. For example, styling elements of a calendar are confused, again until the next pixel width larger or smaller, after which it is all as expected.

Comment: This is exactly the sort of behaviour that can happen with overlapping or ill-matched media queries e.g. `max-width: 720px`  in one and `min-width:720px` in another, resulting in un-synchronised behaviour of the 2 elements. Without a specific example as @Martin suggests (i.e. an actual code example so that we can see it) it is impossible to tell. Also, the media queries define what happens on specific screen sizes, and they are *always* whole pixels :) so what happens on the transition from one pixel width to another isn't usually an issue.

Comment: @FluffyKitten: Got it. I have cut and pasted the media queries themselves to illustrate how I am making the declarations. They are not ill-matched—that was the first thing that I considered—but there may be something else obvious in the syntax which more experienced users will notice. Also, I *do* understand that screen declarations are meant to involve whole pixels, *yet fractional declarations nevertheless modify the behaviour.* I am not making any judgement about what exactly might be happening, but the fact that it is happening should raise eyebrows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's difficult to give a specific answer without seeing what you are seeing, but it's possible that the browsers are handling the transition from one media query to the next in different ways discussed below.

**Most Likely Cause: Windows Display Settings**

I assume you are using Windows when you mention Edge, I suspect this might be because you have changed the scale of your display in **Windows - Display Settings**. If this is set to 125% for example, this can have an affect on *all* aspects of your display.

So really this isn't a *bug with the media queries*, so much as a discrepancy caused by the browsers *not effectively handling the scaling* by Windows Display settings.

---

**UPDATE** - Now that you have confirmed that you can stop on a particular point where this happens, then I'm pretty confident this is the cause. In my testing yesterday when looking into this, I was able to reproduce that behaviour when the display was scaled.

Using the following test case with original styling of an empty block with a red border, and different CSS applied at `(max-width: 1119px)` and `(min-width: 1120px)`, the issue happens ***only when the display is scaled***.

```css
body{ margin:50px 0 0 0;}

.test {
  border: 10px solid #f00;
  height: 10px;
}

@media (min-width: 1120px) {
  .test {
    background: #ff0;
    height: 500px
  }
}

@media (min-width: 720px) and (max-width: 1119px) {
  .test {
    margin-left: 300px;
    background: #0FF;
    height: 200px
  }
}

@media (min-width: 460px) and (max-width: 719px) {
  .test {
    margin-left: 300px;
    background: #00f;
    height: 200px
  }
}

@media (max-width: 460px) {
  .test {
    background: #ff0;
    height: 100px
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

**Firefox, using Dev Console ruler to show window size:**

***Display Scale: 100% (i.e. no scaling) at 1119px width*** - CSS works as expected*

```
@media (min-width: 720px) and (max-width: 1119px) {
  .test { margin-left: 300px; background: #0FF; height: 200px }
}
```

[image: 1119px in non-scaled window]

***Display Scale 125% at 1119px width*** - no CSS media query applied, so CSS reverts to original

```
.test { border: 10px solid #f00; height: 10px; }
```

[image: 1119px in scaled window]

---

**Possible Reason for the "glitch"**

If the above is the case (or even if it isn't), I suspect your next question is why is it happening. Only the developers can answer that, but thinking logically we can come up with the reasoning below.

***What are media queries meant to do?***

First, we need to look at the purpose of media queries. According to the [W3C CSS3 Media Queries recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/):

> The ‘width’ media feature describes the width of the targeted display area of the output device.

From this, we can assume they were intended for selecting the CSS to use depending on the media query that matches the screen/window size. Screen size can't have fractional pixels (e.g. 719.5px) and points between the whole pixels can only "exist" while the screen is being resized, and media queries are not intended to cover such temporary transitions.

OK, that's the *why* it isn't necessarily a "bug" and why it isn't always handled well in browsers, now...

***What is causing this issue to happen during transitions?***

If you have changed the scale, the browser has to recalculate the all the sizes to scale them up/down also. This "glitch" in the transition is most likely being caused by these calculations resulting in fractions of pixels. (If you haven't changed the scale, the same logic actually still applies)

It appears the browsers such as ***Chrome*** have been build to handle the recalculations/ size change in whole pixels, so the display will jump from the CSS applied by (e.g.) `max-width:719px` media query to the CSS for `min-width:720px`.

However other browsers such as ***Firefox*** don't seem to work like this and try to calculate the display based on the fractional pixels. This means there can be instances where the recalculated/changing size fall between e.g. `max-width:719px` nor `min-width:720px`.

In this case it seems to change the display to whatever CSS applies at that point - if there is another media query overlapping those sizes that would be applied, but more likely the *original CSS* is getting applied. So what you are seeing in that transition you describe is your CSS that exists outside of the media queries, e.g. if your CSS is written for mobile-first then you are seeing the CSS for mobile version of the site.

---

**What can we do to "fix" it?**

Aside from changing back the scale to 100% (which isn't a feasible option because you can't ask all your visitors to do that!) I don't know if there is a reliable solution.

- One option is to use decimal values in your media queries like you mentioned, e.g.

```
@media (min-width: 720px) and (max-width: 1119.999px) { /* CSS....*/ }
@media (max-width: 719.999px) { /* CSS....*/ }
```

- Another is to try is to make sure that you have suitable styling in your original CSS that will be applied at the "in-between" points, e.g. 719px - 720px.

Comment: Thank you for your considered response. Everything you have said makes sense. Unfortunately, it doesn't describe well what I am seeing. I have tried different scales, but it doesn't change the behaviour. In both browsers, the transition point, which is a single pixel, is confused. And to be clear, too, it occurs at a specific screen size *that I stop on*. That is, at some point, the browser is selecting certain CSS from one set of rules and certain CSS from another. It appears to be mainly one item—the title bar size—that is being altered early, thereby confusing the rest of the display.

Comment: But I think the crux of what you are saying is correct: I have to find a way around it. As the commentator posted a long time ago, it is so unlikely to be encountered by a real user. And this is perhaps why others have not encountered it either. Indeed, I am particularly obsessive, and it took me a considerable time before I realised there was a problem. I am going to play around and see if I can find a way that it can be averted.

Comment: @POD Maybe my answer wasn't clear, but that is to do with the scaling in Windows Display Settings. Did you check what your sis set at? I'd be confident it is not 100%! It wasn't clear in your question that you could *stop* at a specific point, so I didn't go into detail about that behaviour and concentrated on transitions. I actually saw that behaviour yesterday when I was checking this, and I've updated my answer to include details of this. So really it isn't a bug with the media queries so much as how the browsers handle *or fail to handle!) the windows scaling.

Comment: I find myself wanting to give you another ‘up’ vote, just for all that effort you've put in. Thank you! I agree with your assessment. (That was a nice bit of detective work!) I had never noticed that the default or ‘recommended’ scale setting was 125%, so I didn't even think of it. Unfortunately, I can't find any combination of standard parameters that keep both sets of browsers happy, though. If I put `@media (max-width: 719.999px) { /* CSS....*/ }`, the styling in Chrome and Opera is confused instead, so my work-around below seems to be the only way around it for the moment.

Comment: @POD Glad to help! I had noticed this behaviour myself before but never looked into it, so your question piqued my interest. Unfortunately there's not a lot we can do about the scaling directly - we can't ask users to change their settings to prevent it! - but at least now we know what's happening. Now we just have to hope the developers take this into account in a future version :)

Answer (score 4):

Firefox and Edge appear to calculate and store their view port widths as floating point numbers, and media queries are applied to those values rather than the whole-pixel widths that they represent. There is consequently a difference in the way in which the parameters of our media queries are interpreted.

So whilst Chrome and Opera transition between 720 pixels and 719 pixels seamlessly, the same transition on Firefox or Edge can result in the browsers' simply skipping over the query and applying whatever default styling is otherwise relevant.

My original solution was to apply a browser-specific @media query to account for values between the whole pixels.

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() /* Firefox */
{
    @media only screen and (min-width: 719.000001px) and (max-width: 719.999999px)
    {
```

However, **the real problem was the way in which I was specifying the parameters of the media queries.** Unlike in programming languages, in which we can (and should) define mathematical parameters with equality and inequality (e.g. -1 ≤ x ≤ 1), CSS employs a hierarchy. For example, if `@media (max-width: 600px)` is followed by `@media (max-width: 400px)`, whilst the two are not logically exclusive, the latter query will take precedence over the former.

So my solution was to change the way in which the @media queries were structured, such that there were *max-width* declarations only. If we try to define upper and lower limits of each interval, we run into the aforementioned problems with the way that the distinct browsers interpret the limits.

Comment: Just curious why you don't just use `(max-width: 719.999px)` and `(min-width: 720px) and (max-width: 1119.9999px)` etc in your standard? This rules out the requirement for additional sets of CSS rules for that 1px gap. And you don't need to target specific browsers either.

Answer (score 2):

You could avoid any requirement to set up specific decimals by having no gaps between your queries at all.

### For example:

```
(min-width 1px)      // Instead of (max-width: 719px)
(min-width 720px)    // Instead of (min-width: 720px) and (max-width: 1119px)
(min-width 1120px )  // Instead of (min-width: 1120px)
```

Currently, you have a middle band with one 'max-width' band and one 'min-width' band either side of it.

The above alternative solution just uses 1 direction (min-width), so there are no gaps to contend with.

### Or:

That solution assumes you don't want to develop your whole front-end style for sub-720px and then media-query every larger size.

If you did want to do that, you could always just use the following: (sure Google search SEO may love you, but you may hate it!)

```
(min-width 720px)    // Instead of (min-width: 720px) and (max-width: 1119px)
(min-width 1120px )  // Instead of (min-width: 1120px)
```

You would then need to incorporate your code that you wanted to put in your `max-width: 719px` media query into your base ("non- media query") code.

### Which one?

I'd use the first solution.

Based on the OP, that one would be more applicable in that situation too.

Actually, I wouldn't use the first solution. I'd code for, say, >1230px, and then use media queries that use `max-width` for the responsive steps below that.

Comment: Yes, that is the solution that I found. (I essentially added the same point to my answer below, explaining why this is preferable.) Thank you for your response.

Comment: Why the use of min-width: 1px here? Why a media query at all for the base size?

Comment: Edited to clarify.