# How to apply formatting that is conditional on browser AND screen width

Tags: css

I would like to apply CSS to my site only for a ***specific width AND specific browser***. Specifically, I would like to apply certain formatting *only* when the width is within a certain range, AND the browser is Firefox OR Edge.

*Is it possible to logically combine media queries in this way?*

Thank you.

Comment: You can [combine queries using 'and'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries#and) if that's what you mean.

Comment: Thank you, @rayhatfield. I did know about the logical ‘and’, but I don't know specifically what it would look like when combining browser and viewport width queries.

Comment: Curious why you’re trying to target specific browsers. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @rayhatfield: Yes. I have discovered a [bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63637584/bug-with-browsers-interpretation-of-media-queries) in the interpretation of CSS media queries (specifically, those related to the width of the view port) with certain browsers. I have also found a work-around, but unfortunately one which throws out the styling of the other browsers that are behaving as expected. I therefore want to provide styling for a specific range of view port widths, but *only for Firefox and Edge*.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://www.ryadel.com/en/css3-media-query-target-only-ie-ie6-ie11-firefox-chrome-safari-edge/)?