# Why do I need to add an extra pixel for a max height when using media queries?

Tags: css, media-queries

I have this here code running on 3840x2160 at 225% zoom

```css
#d1 {
  height: 400px;
  width: 275px;
  background-color: hotpink;
}

@media (max-height: 850px) {
  #d1 {
    height: 400px;
    width: 275px;
    background-color: green;
  }
}

@media (max-height: 818px) {
  #d1 {
    height: 400px;
    width: 275px;
    background-color: purple;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="d1"></div>
```

When I don't have the bookmark bar open, the d1 will have background color of hotpink, but when I check the window height it shows 850px, when I show the bookmark bar, the window height is 818px and then d1 background color goes to green.

Now if I add 1 more pixel to the max height

```
@media (max-height: 851px) {
    #d1 {
        height: 400px;
        width: 275px;
        background-color: green;
    }
}

@media (max-height: 819px) {
    #d1 {
        height: 400px;
        width: 275px;
        background-color: purple;
    }
}
```

Then when I hide the bookmark bar, I get the background color of green and when I show the bookmark bar, the background color goes to purple.

So my question is, why do I need to add an extra pixel to the max height to get this to work properly?

Comment: Is this specific to a browser such as chrome or all browsers?

Comment: I've only checked in Chrome

Comment: does #d1 have any border? Did you check the box-sizing for it?

Comment: I don't know how much this might help but have you tried using `vh` instead? The bookmark bar is not supposed to be part of the viewport. Using `vh` might be useful here

Comment: You will have to take pixel value rounding of the browser into account. 850.25px is larger than 850px but will be rounded down to 850px. Also depends on how the browser implemented '@media' calculations. BTW Chrome = Edge (as of 2020), they share the same codebase...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bug with browsers' interpretation of @media queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63637584/bug-with-browsers-interpretation-of-media-queries)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Browsers tend to... not use whole numbers.

What's probably happening is even though dev tools SAYS your window is 850px tall, it's probably 850.25px tall.

As such, since 850.25px is bigger than 850px, the media query doesn't trigger.

(Keep in mind that your entire viewport is being divided by 225% since you're zoomed in, so it's very unlikely that the math will come out to a whole number...)